# Is there a way to model time as an outcome?

Tags: inference

I want to see if there is a relationship between if someone bought a grocery store item and the time of day?
For example, is there a relationship between when someone bought an apple and the time of day? Or when someone bought meat and the time of day?

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Apple_Bought = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Meat_Bought = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Time = c("4/11/22 7:32", "4/14/22 8:20", 
"8/2/22 13:41", "1/28/20 12:20", "5/20/22 10:12", "9/18/21 12:15", 
"8/4/22 15:48", "8/1/20 12:48", "7/11/21 1:31", "1/17/20 9:10", 
"7/11/22 11:31", "4/15/22 8:24", "7/13/22 10:30")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Please note that this is a toy example as I cannot post the real dataset.
Also, i'm not sure if this is the correct forum for this kind of question, so kindly redirect me if not!

Comment: Why would you model time as an outcome? I would think the more natural assumption is that time influences purchases.

Comment: As Shawn, I don't think you should model time as the outcome. Maybe check the purchase frequencies visually and make a time category variable based on what you see (e.g. morning, midday, afternoon, evening) and run a cross-tabulation with chi-square test between time category and product type. Or maybe a count regression with number of purchases as dependent and product type and time (modeled either as categorical or continuous) and their interaction as predictors?

Comment: @Sointu, thank you for your feedback, that makes sense! I was also thinking the same. I think Sointu's suggestion is good, so I will do that instead

Comment: Great, @Nat! I hope it works!